# Meaning of “bile” from Great Expectations

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, literary-english, charles-dickens

In the book *Great Expectations* by Charles Dickens, the character Joe tells Pip,

> “Somebody must keep the pot a **biling**, Pip, or the pot won’t **bile**, don't you know?”

What does the word *bile* mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s just [eye-dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) for *boil*. The character Joe is speaking with a non-standard or rustic diction and accent, and Dickens is using funny spellings to show that.

In the broader passage surrounding that particular quotation I give below, I’ve set such deviations from Standard English in bold:

> “Though mind you, Pip,” said Joe, with a judicial touch or two of the poker on the top bar, “rendering unto all their **doo**, and maintaining equal justice betwixt man and man, my father **were** that good in his **hart**, don’t you see?”
>
> I didn’t see, but I didn’t say so.
>
> “Well!” Joe pursued, “somebody must keep the pot a **biling**, Pip, or the pot won’t **bile**, don’t you know.”
>
> I saw that, and said so.
>
> “ ’**Consequence**, my father didn’t make objections to my going to work; so I went to work at my present calling, which **were** his too, if he would have followed it, and I worked **tolerable** hard, I assure *you*, Pip.  In time I **were** able to keep him, and I **kep** him till he went off in a **purple** **leptic** fit. And it **were** my intentions to have had put upon his tombstone that **Whatsume’er** the failings on his part, Remember reader he **were** that good in his **hart**.”

Comment: If I'm not completely misinterpreting this, *"purple leptic"* an eggcorn for *"epileptic"* here. So shouldn't you put **purple** in bold as well?

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, probably. I hadn’t originally because I can imagine someone dying in a “purple” epileptic fit.

Comment: @PeterShor: or possibly, "a purple leptic" is an eggcorn for "an apoplectic"

Comment: @sumelic: Given when *Great Expectations* was written, that's probably more likely.